# Eigenvalues of a Laplacian in NetworkX

Tags: scipy, networkx

NetworkX has a decent code example for getting all the eigenvalues of a Laplacian matrix, given below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy.linalg

n = 1000  # 1000 nodes
m = 5000  # 5000 edges
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n, m)

L = nx.normalized_laplacian_matrix(G)
e = numpy.linalg.eigvals(L.A)
print("Largest eigenvalue:", max(e))
print("Smallest eigenvalue:", min(e))
plt.hist(e, bins=100)  # histogram with 100 bins
plt.xlim(0, 2)  # eigenvalues between 0 and 2
plt.show()
```

For the most part I follow all of this until you hit `numpy.linalg.eigvals(L.A)`. What's the `.A` bit doing? I've looked at the documentation for sparse matrixes in SciPy, but I can't find a reference to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L.A` is shorthand for `L.toarray()`. It is the matrix representation of the matrix object.